# Fastest way to find a String into an array of string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, loops, comparison

The script has to verify if one predefined IP is present in a big array of IPs. Currently I code that function like this (saying that "ips" is my array of IP and "ip" is the predefined ip)

```
ips.each do |existsip|
  if ip == existsip
    puts "ip exists"
    return 1
  end
end
puts "ip doesn't exist"
return nil
```

Is there a faster way to do the same thing?

Edit : I might have wrongly expressed myself. I can do array.include? but what I'd like to know is : Is array.include? the method that will give me the fastest result?

Comment: Use a Hash or Set instead of an array

Comment: Read http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html before any Ruby programming.

Comment: You can use the `include?` method defined in class `Array` to make this operation look neater, I am not sure if it will increase the speed of the lookup much

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140554/ruby-on-rails-2-search-string-in-hash

Comment: @JosephLeBrech The question here is about searching an array.

Comment: Given the updated question, the answer is to not use an array of strings at all.  The answer below that uses the `Set` class is a much better method.

Comment: If absolute speed is critical, using symbols instead of strings for the IPs may provide a small benefit (after you first switch to use either a Hash or Set).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). It is implemented on top of Hash and will be faster for big datasets  - O(1).

```
require 'set'
s = Set.new ['1.1.1.1', '1.2.3.4']
# => #<Set: {"1.1.1.1", "1.2.3.4"}> 
s.include? '1.1.1.1'
# => true
```

Comment: Or in your case: `s = Set.new(ips)`

Comment: Hello again Alex :) .include method source code seems to do almost the same thing as mine. Or is it actually faster?

Comment: @Cocotton: [Much faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551168/performance-of-arrays-and-hashes-in-ruby/5552062#5552062). You could also use a Hash with ip's as keys and 'true' as values.

Comment: @steenslag,Phrogz : For now I'll leave it like this (.include), but when I'll be done will my script, I'll switch it for a hash

Comment: The obvious caveat here is that the Set is faster, but building the Set can be an expensive operation, so you wouldn't want to build a set to query it a small number of times.

Comment: For an array of 12.4 million short strings: `a=('a'..'zzzzz').to_a; time{ a.include?('0') } #=> 0.71s; time{ Set.new(a) } #=> 11.2s`; so yes, the overhead of creating the set needs to be worth the performance gains of instantaneous queries.

Comment: Backing up @Phrogz statement, check the source code of both #include? methods and this gist as proof: https://gist.github.com/vadviktor/66e524c591b2604ce2d7

Answer (score 6):

You could use the Array#include method to return you a true/false.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

```
if ips.include?(ip) #=> true
  puts 'ip exists'
else
  puts 'ip  doesn\'t exist'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ips = ['10.10.10.10','10.10.10.11','10.10.10.12']

ip = '10.10.10.10'
ips.include?(ip) => true

ip = '10.10.10.13'
ips.include?(ip) => false
```

**[check Documentaion here](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000441)**

Comment: But is this actually faster than my method? Because the source code of this seems to do practically the same thing as mine.

Comment: ofcourse it is faster.. i have using in my project.. moreover when there is a method in ruby, why should we write extra code.

Comment: @dku.rajkumar wanted to say, it should be faster as `.include?` is implemented on C level on the Array class.

Answer (score 3):

A faster way would be:

```
if ips.include?(ip)
  puts "ip exists"
  return 1
else
  puts "ip doesn't exist"
  return nil
end
```

Comment: Slightly faster, since the `each` occurs in C instead of Ruby, but it's still O(n) versus O(1) for a Hash or Set.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried the Array#include? function?

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

You can see from the source it does almost exactly the same thing, except natively.

Comment: This is still an O(n) time operation, as it must search through every item in the array (even if it's in C).

Comment: I know that an enum can be sorted, but I don't know how to search such a sorted array.  One could make an indexed database column to do the job.

Comment: Even a binary search is O(log n). Hashing an item and looking it up in a hash table is a constant-time operation that is unrelated to the number of items stored.