# What is the most accurate way to sniff out substrings in unpredictable strings of words in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, sorting, split, substring

I'm working on a cash register.  The input is lists of items, like the following:

```
1 table at 92.49
1 chair at 44.59
1 imported rug at 580.99
1 set of imported cups at 83.79
```

As you can see, the position of the word "imported" does not follow a fixed standard, but I want the output to be as follows (notice the word "at" is also omitted and replaced by a colon):

```
1 table: 92.49
1 chair: 44.59
1 imported rug: 580.99
1 imported set of cups: 83.79
```

I did this by

```
.each do |line|
```

for the input file, and removing array.first and array.last of line.split

```
    getElements = []
    getElements << line.split

    leftSnippet = getElements.first.first

    rightSnippet = getElements.last.last

    itemName = line.delete! leftSnippet + rightSnippet

    sort_Imported = []

      if sort_Imported[0] == "imported"
        itemName = itemName.gsub!(/ imported/, "")
        itemName = itemName[0...-5]

      elsif sort_Imported.include? "imported"
        itemName = itemName.gsub!(/ imported/, "")
        itemName = itemName[0...-4]

      else itemName = itemName[0...-5]
    end
```

leaving me with something like follows:

```
table at
chair at
imported rug at
set of imported cups at
```

The reason I wrote this part:

```
sort_Imported = []
sort_Imported << newItemName.split
sort_Imported = sort_Imported.first

    if sort_Imported[0] == "imported"
      itemName = itemName.gsub!(/ imported/, "")
      itemName = itemName[0...-5]

  elsif sort_Imported.include? "imported"
    itemName = itemName.gsub!(/ imported/, "")
    itemName = itemName[0...-5]

  else itemName = itemName[0...-5]
end
```

...is because some very strange things were happening when I added the ":" and the prices at the end involving spaces and missing characters.  Something like follows:

```
table :
chair:
imported rug:
imported set of  cup:
```

The messing with the -4 and -5 allowed me to get the result I wanted for my data set, BUT I don't like how it is hard-coded in because if I have different types of items the same kind of problem will arise.

So I'm wondering am I going about this all wrong, if there is a less clumsy way to get these substrings?  It's the only logical conclusion I have been able to reach since the nature of the item names is that they could literally be anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby - Fastest way to find a string into an array of string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313957/ruby-fastest-way-to-find-a-string-into-an-array-of-string)

Comment: Can you identify the list of unwanted sub strings and than remove them by running them through a loop. So one loop for replacing ' at' with ':' and one loop for removing unwanted sub strings.

Comment: I've done that already, the problem is when I sort the word "imported" to the front of the item name and put all the substrings back together again, it is not uniform with the spaces and placement of the colon.  Sometimes it deletes the last character at the end of the item name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like:

```
lines = [
  '1 table at 92.49',
  '1 chair at 44.59',
  '1 imported rug at 580.99',
  '1 set of imported cups at 83.79',
]

puts lines.map{ |line|
  new_line = line.sub(/ at /, ': ')
  if new_line[' imported ']
    new_line = new_line.split.reject{ |s| s['imported'] }.insert(1, 'imported').join(' ')
  end
  new_line
}
# >> 1 table: 92.49
# >> 1 chair: 44.59
# >> 1 imported rug: 580.99
# >> 1 imported set of cups: 83.79
```

Here's what's happening:

```
line = '1 set of imported cups at 83.79'

new_line = line.sub(/ at /, ': ') # => "1 set of imported cups: 83.79"
new_line = new_line.split         # => ["1", "set", "of", "imported", "cups:", "83.79"]
  .reject{ |s| s['imported'] }    # => ["1", "set", "of", "cups:", "83.79"]
  .insert(1, 'imported')          # => ["1", "imported", "set", "of", "cups:", "83.79"]
  .join(' ')                      # => "1 imported set of cups: 83.79"
```

Here are the details:

- I use `/ at /` because I only want to replace the word at, not a substring `'at'` that happens to match. Similarly, I use `' imported '` to make sure I don't find a substring.
- `split` breaks a string on whitespace, effectively returning each word. That makes it easy to remove any/all occurrences of `"imported"`.
- `insert(1, 'imported')` inserts `"imported"` where I want it.

Finally, your use of variable names is not idiomatic Ruby. Follow the standard or suffer the scorn of coworkers in code-reviews:

```
getElements   --> get_elements
leftSnippet   --> left_snippet
rightSnippet  --> right_snippet
itemName      --> item_name
sort_Imported --> sort_imported
newItemName   --> new_item_name
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.  It now works for any kind of input.  Also, thanks for the tip about the variable naming conventions.  I've updated my entire code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
itemName.gsub(/ at/, ':').gsub(/set of imported (\w*)/, 'imported set of \1')
```

Comment: Hello, I need a bit more of a detailed solution, because other items could be "case of X" or "bag of Y" or "box of Z".  Thank you.

Comment: gsub(/(set|case|bag|box) of imported (\w*)/, 'imported \1 of \2')

Comment: or if there are future possibilities that you don't even know about: gsub(/(\w*) of imported (\w*)/, 'imported \1 of \2')

Comment: The arbitrary use of `gsub` instead of `sub` will cause your code to run more slowly, approximately 10% slower for each occurrence from my testing. Use `sub` when there's only one substitution that should occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to cut off the beginning and end parts, saving them for later.

When then `join` the middle together, and if we see "imported" we'll cut it out using `gsub` and replace it at the beginning, capturing the rest of the string in the regexps using `()` so we can use them in the replacement. Then we just need to put the quantity and price in.

```
lines.each do |ln|
  parts = ln.split
  mid = parts[1..-2].join(' ') # skip quantity(1), and at(-2) price(-1)
  #move around imported
  mid.gsub!(/(.+) (imported )(.+)/, "#{$2} #{$1} #{$3}") 
  #put it all together
  puts "#{parts[0]} #{mid} #{parts[-1]}"
end
```